# Как правильно определять тип устройства в NextJs приложении?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, nextjs

Нужно адаптировать приложение NextJs под мобильные устройства.
Как же всё так правильно?

Определять тип устройства в getServerSideProps?

Или делать это через хук useMediaQuery?

Comment: все зависит от того, что ты считаешь мобильным устройством и что конкретно хочешь адаптировать?

Comment: Ну я имею ввиду если с телефона заходишь то хедер такой отображается, если с компа, то другой

Comment: И так другие элементы, менять их порядок ширину и тд

Comment: куча способов, все зависит от того что на что должно меняться. Можно вообще без getServerSideProps и useMediaQuery - одними media запросами в css

Comment: Может я не до конца понимаю

Comment: что именно ты не понимаешь?

Comment: Ведь когда используешь getServerSideProps html генерируется на стороне сервера как и данные, и прилетают на клиент, если использовать useMediaQueryна клиенте то по сути получается весь ssr на смарку

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145701/discussion-between-grundy-and-alexanderkomarchev).

Answer (score -1):

В  [**документации nextjs**](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching/get-server-side-props) написано -

> getServerSideProps only runs on server-side and never runs on the
> browser.

Перевод:

> getServerSideProps вызывается только на сервере, он не вызывается в
> браузере.

Возникает такой логичный вопрос. **Как вы собираетесь определить тип устройства пользователя на сервере?**

---

Как мне известно вы не сможете это сделать с помощью `getServerSideProps`, `getStaticProps` или на другой функции который предоставляет некст из коробки.

У вас остается два решения:

Либо через сторонние npm пакеты, либо через css или его препроцессоры. Я бы сделал через второй вариант потому что не хочу устанавливать лишние зависимости.

Comment: _Как вы собираетесь определить тип устройства пользователя на сервере?_ - точно так же как и на клиенте - по user agent

Comment: @Grundy ну попробуйте, покажите реализацию.

Comment: реализацию чего? Получения заголовка из запроса или разбора строки user agent?

Comment: @Grundy __реализацию чего?__ -> что мы сейчас обсуждаем? Мне интересно как вы читаете переписку.

Comment: Задача делится на два шага, получение user-agent, получение типа устройства на основе user-agent. Какой именно шаг тебе непонятен - неизвестно, поэтому и был задан уточняющий вопрос.